# Сортировка Map по значению из value

Tags: java, сортировка

Есть `Map<String, Warp>`.
У класса `Warp` есть метод `getVisits();`

Мне нужно получить 10 наиболее посещаемых варпов (`getVisits();` - количество посещений). Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш класс:

```
class Warp implements Comparable<Warp> {

    private int visits;

    public Warp(int visits) {
        this.visits = visits;
    }

    // getters & setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull Warp o) {
        return this.visits - o.visits;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Warp{" +
                "visits=" + visits +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Создаём и заполняем `map`:

```
Map<String, Warp> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
    map.put("test_" + i, new Warp(i));
}
```

Если вывести `map` в консоль:

> {test_39=Warp{visits=39}, test_38=Warp{visits=38}, test_37=Warp{visits=37}, ..., test_86=Warp{visits=86}, test_85=Warp{visits=85}, test_84=Warp{visits=84}, test_83=Warp{visits=83}}

Сортируем и собираем в список:

```
List<Warp> list = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Выводим `list` в консоль:

> [Warp{visits=1}, Warp{visits=2}, Warp{visits=3}, Warp{visits=4}, Warp{visits=5}, Warp{visits=6}, Warp{visits=7}, Warp{visits=8}, Warp{visits=9}, Warp{visits=10}]

В вашем случае нужен обратный порядок сортировки:

```
.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
```